# Confused about a step in a proof that $a\times (b \times c) = (a\cdot c)b - (b\cdot c)a$

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, vectors, proof-explanation, inner-products

Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}^3$. I'm trying to understand a step in [a proof](https://www.vedantu.com/iit-jee/vector-triple-product) of the result

$$a\times (b \times c) = (a\cdot c)b - (b\cdot c)a.$$

The author begins with $a\times (b \times c) = xa+yb$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$, and then writes

$$
c\cdot(xa+yb) = x(c\cdot a)+y(c\cdot b) = 0.$$

**Why is the result equal to zero?**

Comment: Check the proof again. It states that $a \times (b \times c) = xb + yc$, not $xa + yb$. The reason this should make sense is that $v = a \times (b \times c)$ is normal to $b \times c$, and since $b \times c$ is normal to $b$ and $c$, you get that $v$ is parallel to the plane spanned by $b$ and $c$, and thus a linear combination of $b,c$ (try drawing a picture). Then you'd have that $a \cdot v = 0$ (can you see why?)

Comment: You have a typo. The website begins the proof with $(a\times b)\times c$, which is clearly orthogonal to $c$ so taking dot product of this with $c$ yields $0$. You're taking $a\times(b\times c)$.

Answer (score 1):

That website's presentation is not too clear and has some minor typos as well; I would suggest [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) as an alternative.

In any case, keeping with your setup, first keep the following property in mind:

RULE 1: The cross product between two vectors is always orthogonal to both vectors.

So first off, going along with your website, in your setup it should be $(a\times b)\times c=xa+yb$ for some scalars $x,y$; this is not the same as what you have since the cross product is not associative.

Ok, so why can we write the triple product $(a\times b)\times c$  as a linear combo of $a$ and $b$? By rule 1, this triple product must be orthogonal to $a\times b$; since $a\times b$ is itself orthogonal to $a,b$ by rule 1, then this triple product is *coplanar* to $a,b$ allowing us to write it as a linear combo of the two.

By rule 1, the triple product is also orthogonal to $c$ and this gives the zero result that you are confused about.

Answer (score 0):

I am just a student so I hope that my answer is correct.

#### Question:

$a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^3$ prove that $a \times (b \times c) =  (a \cdot c) b - (a \cdot b) c$

#### Answer:

1- First of all let remind that for any $u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ we have that $u \times v \perp Span(u,v)$.
Hence $b \times c \perp Span(b,c)$ and so following the same logic the vector $a \times (b \times c) \perp Span(a; b \times c)$.

2-Now as $a,b,c$ are not colinear so $\mathbb{R}^3=Span(a;b;c)$ and thus $a \times (b \times c) \in Span(b,c)$ as it can not be that $a \times (b \times c) \in Span(a; b \times c)$.

3-So can be written as $a \times (b \times c) = \lambda_1 b + \lambda_2 c$. But because that we have $a \times (b \times c) \cdot a $ is necessarily equal to zero as it is a dot product between $a$ and $a \times (b \times c)$ two vectors  $a \perp a \times (b \times c)$.
So $a \cdot (\lambda_1 b + \lambda_2 c) = 0 = a \cdot \lambda_1 b +a \cdot \lambda_2 c \Rightarrow - \lambda_2 a \cdot c = \lambda_1 a \cdot  b \Rightarrow \frac{- \lambda_2}{a \cdot  b}=\frac{\lambda_1}{a \cdot  c}=\lambda $.
So we can re writte $\lambda_1 b + \lambda_2 c = \lambda (a \cdot c) b - \lambda (a \cdot b) c$

4-To finish we need to prove that $\lambda = 1 $.
In order to do that we will first prove that $\lambda$ does not depend of $a,b,c$ it means that $\lambda$ is the same $\forall a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}^3$. And indeed note that $a \times (b \times c) \perp Span(a; b \times c)$ is linear.
Now take easy $a,b,c$ in order to find the value of $\lambda$, i.e. $a=i,b=j,c=k \Rightarrow \lambda =1$

Q.E.D.